# Zooming in ScrollView works in iOS4 but crash in iOS5 and iOS5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a application that in iOS4.3 works perfectly well, but crash in iOS5 and iOS5.1 (the error is described below).
The problem is only the zooming of a scrollView.
I have the scrollView inside one UIView(This UIView besides the scrollView has others stuff(UILabels,UIButtons,...)), and I only want to zoom the scrollView.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {

    return MyScrollView;

}
```

Error message:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'The view returned from viewForZoomingInScrollView: must be a subview of the scroll view. It can not be the scroll view itself.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception already tells you what to do. Create another `UIView` subview for the scroll view and put all the scroll view's current subviews there, then return that one in `viewForZoomingInScrollView`.

Comment: Can i do that(create another view and put all the scroll view's current) programmatically? or the best way is doing on interface builder?

Comment: You can do both. Just iterate over all the scroll views subviews and add them to the intermediate view instead.